# Nmap Performance Mass Scanning SSL/TLS Certificate Data

Tags: dell, nmap

Is Nmap built to use all of the available resources eg. in a server such as **Dell PowerEdge T620 Server Xeon 16 Core 2.6GHz 128GB RAM** with connectivity to both network ports? Basically, would the program take avantage of the extra CPU, Networking availability to drastically improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

No, nmap is single process. You would need to run multiple nmap commands, and even if you did it is unlikely it will fully utilize your hardware.

Scripts written in the [Lua-based nmap scripting engine](https://nmap.org/book/nse-parallelism.html) can behave asynchronously, which may help performance.